# How to enable Smart Search automatic indexing?

Tags: smartsearch, search

This page, [Setting up automatic Smart Search indexing](http://docs.joomla.org/Setting_up_automatic_Smart_Search_indexing), from the Joomla! Documentation states that Smart Search automatically indexes content once it has been amended. However, I've found on a site I'm working on that this isn't the case - I have to manually index content for it to appear, or set up a cron job.

How is smart search automatic indexing meant to work? Is it via the 'Content - Smart Search' plugin via a plugin hook? If so, do any other config items need to be set to get it working?

Comment: What is not indexed in your case? I found that after creating content it indexes it automatically.

Comment: I received a report from a client that articles, once created, were not appearing in the search results. Having just looked closer I completely missed the fact they omitted certain categories from the search filter. My bad.

Comment: Maybe there is a search filter active that does not include some category that may have been created since the initial indexing? or just a search filter that is meant to not include those articles?

Comment: That was the case - for some reason the client arbitrarily omitted certain categories that needed to be indexed.

Comment: FYI. I have no filters setup and the plugins enabled and I still have to manually index my site. Just thought you should know. Joomla 3.8 Stable. Also, they have no search plugin for "title" which I find amazingly stupid. Why can't the front end search work as well as the backend article search... Just wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, my client failed to correctly configure the Search Filter for the site, omitting certain categories but not others so it appeared as if some content was being missed.

Comment: The content may have been indexed (you can check that in the smart search admin), they just need to remove the search filter.